# tablesorter- sort logic for rows with same text

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have a question on how is tablesorter going to sort on a specified column if two rows of that column have same text.

Suppose my table is like

```
 Fruit     User

 Apple     james
 Banana    scot
 Apple     peter
```

If i sort based on column 1, then will it become

```
 Fruit     User

 Apple     james
 Apple     peter
 Banana    scot
```

or

```
 Fruit     User

 Apple     peter
 Apple     james 
 Banana    scot
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the first one, here is a fiddle to show you, click on the headers

http://jsfiddle.net/YKeaS/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parameter `sortForce` for setting the secondary sort.

> Use to add an additional forced sort that will be appended to the dynamic selections by the user. For example, can be used to sort people alphabetically after some other user-selected sort that results in rows with the same value like dates or money due. It can help prevent data from appearing as though it has a random secondary sort.

Check the [documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) for more details